# ascii code of whitespace inside switch

Tags: c

I am not getting ASCII code of white-space.
Please fix and explain it too...

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char choice,ch;
    printf ("Press 'a' to find ASCII code of character: ");
    scanf ("%c",&choice);
   switch(choice)
   {
        case 'a':
            printf ("Enter the character: ");
            scanf (" %c",&ch);
            printf ("The ASCII code of character %c is %d",ch,ch);
        break;
        default:
            printf ("Please enter right key");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf` eats whitespace characters.  Don't use `scanf`, like, ever.

Comment: void main() is not standard C.

Comment: @machine_1 That's true but it also has nothing to do with OP's problem.  For all we know they are using a compiler where that is an officially supported alternative declaration for `main`.

Comment: @zwol scanf eats whitespace characters??
I  don't understand that...please explain

Comment: @willsir Almost all `scanf` formats discard leading whitespace from the input.  %c is an exception, but you have `scanf(" %c")` which explicitly asks for whitespace to be skipped.  See the linked Q&A for what you should be doing instead (namely using `fgets`).